# Pausing Video Record in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture

in my iphone app,I am recording video using UIImagePickerController.
I am recording and stoping like this

```
  [VideoRecorder startVideoCapture];    //Starting Video Record
  [VideoRecorder stopVideoCapture];      //Stoping Video Record
```

Now how can I Pause and Resume the video while recording ?

Comment: You might want to google this topic...there many q/a out there.  Good luck.

Comment: I have googled this,but no solution found

Comment: check http://www.gdcl.co.uk/iOS/capturepause.zip